# How can I find commonly duplicated questions from stack network dumps?

Tags: script

**Why?**
I got tired of searching for the same duplicate questions over and over again.

**What?**
These are a couple of scripts I threw together in order to cut down search time for common questions and vote to close targets.  `dupes.txt` is the output in a flat text file of the form:

Link: `url` Count: `number of times this was cited as the original for a dupe closure`
Link: `url` Count: `number of times this was cited as the original for a dupe closure`
...

It's sorted in descending order of duplicates

Usage: `./dupes.sh posts.xml`
Yields: `./dupes.txt`

dupes.sh

```
#/bin/bash
cat $1 | grep ' ClosedDate\=\"' | grep 'Possible Duplicate' | awk -F 'Possible Duplicate:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xA;  &lt;a href=&quot;' '{print $2}' | awk -F '&quot;&gt;' '{print $1}' | grep questions > dupes.txt  
python dupes.py
```

dupes.py

```
lines = []
with open('dupes.txt', 'r') as dupeList:
    for line in dupeList.readlines():
        lines.append(line.rstrip())

links = {}
for line in lines:
    try:
        links[line] += 1
    except:
        links[line] = 1
thelinks = []
for link in links.keys():
    thelinks.append((link, links[link]))

thelinksort = sorted(thelinks, key=lambda alink: alink[1])

thelinksort.reverse()

with open('dupes.txt', 'w') as dupeList:
    for line in thelinksort:
        dupeList.write('Link: ' + line[0] + ' Count: ' + str(line[1]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Worth mentioning this can also be done with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/1059250)

Comment: I was doing it locally with the data explorer API of text dumps.

Comment: Yes, I saw that and that is fine. Datadumps are a bit less frequently released, quarterly-ish, while SEDE is refreshed weekly.